# How can I add another root user to mysql in debian stretch?

Tags: debian, mysql

I followed this commands from stack overflow, but the new user is unable to create a new user, a database and granting permissions.

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost';
GRANT RELOAD,PROCESS ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'dummy'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.* to user@localhost
```

Alternatively you can connect to the mysql database and run the following commands:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Super_Priv='Y' WHERE user='user1' AND host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

The issue you are having is you are working at the database level, you need to set a global access.  Have a read of [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63404/how-to-grant-super-privilege-to-the-user) link.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why don't they tell the same in all the questions with "how do I make another root account at mysql?"